# Specifiying custom profilers for pyspark running Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I would like to know how to specify a custom profiler class in PySpark for Spark version 2+. Under 1.6, I know I can do so like this:

```py
sc = SparkContext('local', 'test', profiler_cls='MyProfiler')
```

but when I create the `SparkSession` in 2.0 I don't explicitly have access to
the `SparkContext`. Can someone please advise how to do this for Spark 2.0+ ?

Answer (score 1):

`SparkSession` can be initialized with an existing `SparkContext`, for example:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.profiler import BasicProfiler

spark = SparkSession(SparkContext('local', 'test', profiler_cls=BasicProfiler))
```