# How do I set profiler_cls when using SparkSession.builder?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, profiling

I have a python codebase that uses pyspark's `SparkSession.builder` to create a `SparkSession`. I'm at the point where I want to profile the python code that is running.

If I was calling the `SparkContext` constructor directly, I'd be able to pass a `profiler_cls` parameter in. However, using the builder, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this. Am I missing something?  At the moment, it would default to the `BasicProfiler`, but I want to use https://pypi.org/project/pyspark-flame/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A cut down version of the code (removing superfluous config settings) is:

```
SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(app_name) \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g") \
        .config("spark.python.profile", "true") \
        .config("spark.python.profile.dump", ".") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

I'm trying to do this using the builder rather than implementing that code myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifiying custom profilers for pyspark running Spark 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676078/specifiying-custom-profilers-for-pyspark-running-spark-2-0)

Comment: Unfortunately not, thanks. I know how to create it using the session like that and could refactor the code. But the current code it quite nicely using the builder - and I can't see how to configure the profiler using the builder.

Answer (score 0):

The `Builder` class has an undocumented method `_sparkContext`, that lets you specify the spark context for the session, so adding `._sparkContext(SparkContext(profiler_cls=...))` to your builder should work (although I haven't tested it).

But be aware that pyspark-flame (and indeed other profilers that use pyspark's profiling capabilities) can only profile RDDs that run Python code on the workers, whereas Spark SQL does most of its heavy lifting in Java and Scala. Depending on your application, and how heavily you rely on SQL and dataframes, you may or may not get useful data from it.